# radio button doesn't fit inside a table?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, radio-button

i'm working on this calculator and when the user select one of the type a little table should appear to select a type from tha table but the radio button that should be clicked doesn't fit into table

[image: example]

this is lookup in ccs code of table and  the full code in jsfiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ojarnaoui/q58x3s6b/)

```
    table {
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-collapse: collapse;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
table-layout: fixed;
}
.rad
{width:1em;
height:1em;}
table thead,
table tbody {
  display: block;
}
table thead th ,table tbody td
{
  font-size : 12px;
}
table tbody {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: overlay;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
tr:hover{
background-color:gray;
cursor:pointer;
}
table tbody td, table thead th {
  text-align: center;

}

table tbody td:last-child, table thead th:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

table tbody td:first-child, table thead th:first-child {
  width: 10px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(2), table thead th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(3), table thead th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(4), table thead th:nth-child(4) {
  width: 100px;
}
table tbody td:nth-child(5), table thead th:nth-child(5) {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post html as well?

Comment: the html is too long cuz i implemented the table manually to demonstrate here is https://jsfiddle.net/q58x3s6b/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove `position: absolute` from the css for `input[type="radio"]`. Working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/peL0bkvw/).

Comment: ayy thanks i didn't pay attention beacause that is related to another radio button  thanks bro